# Call ajax and passing href value to php script

Tags: jquery, html

According to the link name I want to process data and retrieve a value after processed by the php script. Everything works except I believe that the ajax function isn't being cancelled as long as i could check with chrome.

Can I do something like this:

HTML

```
<a href="test0" class="link">click 0</a>
<a href="test1" class="link">click 1</a>
```

JS script:

```
$(".link").live('click', function(){
       $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/ajax/file.php',
            data: {
                link : $(this).attr('href'),
            },error: function(xhr, error){
                console.debug(xhr); console.debug(error);
            },success: function(data){
                alert(data);
            }
        });
});
```

[image: DevTools Screenshot]

Many thanks.

UPDATE:

The reason I've done this was to get data (files) from the webserver acoording to the user choice, but I realise that this can't be achieved with this technique. The best approach is to use a `<a href="/download.php?file=myfile&token=asdasdlkjsd" page="_blank">file</a>`

Then from the server side we have to use headers and the right mime-types.

If is possible to transfer a file by ajax and let the user decide if open, save or close it then I would like to know how :)

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$(".link")`? Notice the `s` in `slink`

Comment: My mistake sorry, either way it's not working the requests are being cancelled as I said earlier

Comment: What do you mean by "ajax function isn't being cancelled"?

Comment: this $.ajax({ whats inside of the function

Comment: So, what's the issue?  Why would you want the AJAX to be `cancelled`?  Does the `alert` open?  What does the PHP file look like?

Comment: click, live dead it's not the problem here

Comment: I don't... but it is, I check it over chrome tools

Comment: no the alert it's not opening

Comment: @FCC-PT: What is Chrome's tools showing you?  Are there errors in the console?

Comment: @FCC-PT, there is an extra comma-delimeter next to `.attr('href'),`. Is it also a typo? By the way, if `success` is not being called. Can you implement the error callback and log the error message?

Comment: The console doesn't pop up anything. I've updated my question with the error callback please give it a look.

Comment: @FCC-PT: So, does that error callback print anything to your console?  You say that the AJAX is being "cancelled", maybe your PHP script isn't working?

Comment: @Alexander: Unless he is using IE, that doesn't matter :-P

Comment: Nothing... it's just echo a string for now. The php script code: echo "test";

Comment: In Chrome's dev tools (network tab), can you see the AJAX request?  Do you see a response when you click on it?  Is the row red (that means an error on the server)?

Comment: Yes it's red. It say's method: GET Status: canceled Type:pending Initiator: Other

Comment: Every time I click the links, I get this error...

Comment: @FCC-PT: What error?  What is the `Status Code`?  500?  404?

Comment: The red feedback under network :)

Comment: @FCC-PT: There should be a `Status Code` field in the table, what is it?

Comment: I'm sorry, there isn't any kind of output, I just get red words under the network tab as I said earlier. I don't have a clue of what can be wrong.

Comment: @FCC-PT, in this cases you should put a snapshot :)

Comment: @FCC-PT: What are those words?  Can you post a screenshot?

Comment: @FCC-PT: That's probably happening because the browser is trying to follow the link's `href`.  Does [@moonwave99's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14364326/206403) not work for you?  Do you get the same issue with that answer?

Comment: It didn't worked I keep getting the same behavior...

Comment: @FCC-PT: That's strange.  Are you sure you added the `event.preventDefault();` line?

Comment: Copy paste, directly from stack :) made some adjusts to php file name

Comment: @FCC-PT: I don't know what else to do then.  That code seems to be working for me.

Comment: jssssssss I'm done I can't go for submit button what other options do I've got to solve this issue?

Comment: Is your url supposed to be `test0`? :)

Comment: I don't pass anything through url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`live()` is deprecated, use `on()`. Plus you need to prevent default browser behaviour [i.e. following href] with `event.preventDefault()` inside your event handler.

```
$(document).on('click', '.link', function(event){

  event.preventDefault();

     $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '/ajax/file.php',
          data: {
              link : $(this).attr('href'),
          },
          success: function(data){
              alert(data);
          }
      });

});
```

EDIT: pardon me, fixed.

Comment: NOTE: This code is *not* equivalent to the OP's code.  `.live` creates delegated events, this does not.

Comment: You might want to point out that `on` is not just an exact copy of `live`. The way you're using `on` here will not produce the same functionality. You'll have to delegate it.

Comment: So what's the best option?

Comment: hey guys, just a small question: what do you mean be 'delegate' here?

Comment: @doniyor: To `delegate` means to bind the event to a parent of the element, and then check the target.  This makes it so the event will be bound to any elements that are added to the DOM later on.

Comment: @doniyor - You should read the [jQuery docs on **Direct and delegated events**](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Comment: @RocketHazmat and - Joseph: thanks guys. learnt something new! :)

Comment: Yah but not in here, if a place an alert between $.ajax(alert('teste'),{)... the alert pop's up strange but nothing else!

Comment: I fixed it... just a extra character was the problem I'm in need to buy a pair of googles :) indeed.

Thank you all for the efforts.